# Eloquent - Multiple where Clause and orWhere

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I have a little problem to make a query in my laravel application :

I have a table which displays all the customers of my shop.
We are many administrators, and each one have his own shop and his own customers.
The user table has a field 'shop_id' to filter that and the table will only displays the customers who have the same 'shop_id' as the authentified admin.

So I have this query :

```
$customers = Customer::where('shop_id', Auth::user()->shop_id)->paginate(12);
```

But we have a lot of customers, so I want to filter those customers. I use a livewire component to make this filter dynamic with a public $search.
So my new query is :

```
$customers = Customer::where('shop_id', Auth::user()->shop_id)->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(12);
```

Everything's ok if I don't want to add some additionnal filters. But I need to filter by name, by reference_client, and by society name, everything in the same search input.

I thought the next query were correct :

```
$customers = Customer::where('shop_id', Auth::user()->shop_id)->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->orWhere('society', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->orWhere('reference', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(12);
```

But the orWhere clauses cancel the first where clause (relative to shop_id) : the table displays all the customers, not only the customers who have the good 'shop_id'.

I imagine that I have to combine the 'search' queries in a function, but I have some problem to realize that.

I hope someone could help me, it would be great :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I found the solution, a function a the where clause as i thought : $customers = Customer::where('shop_id', Auth::user()->shop_id)->where(function($q) { $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orWhere('company', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orWhere('reference', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%'); })->paginate(12)

Comment: Yeah, you've got it  When you deconstruct this to SQL, you get `WHERE ... AND ... OR ...`, but you're looking for something like `WHERE ... AND (WHERE ... OR ...)` (or similar); if you don't wrap your `where` clauses, they "leak" or cancel each other out, so `->where(function() { ...})` is the correct approach here. Hint: Laravel has a `->toSql()` method so you can see the actual query being executed; that should make it super obvious what is happening. Glad you got it working, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, a function a the where clause as i thought : `$customers = Customer::where('shop_id', Auth::user()->shop_id)->where(function($q) { $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orWhere('company', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orWhere('reference', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%'); })->paginate(12)`